# First (real) boot failure - BSOD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bios, nvme

since yesterday I've been dealing with a problem that I can't seem to resolve. The situation went as follows:

1. I assembled a computer from entirely new parts.
2. I booted it up, and everything was working correctly.
3. I connected a USB with the Windows Installation Tool.
4. I installed Windows 10 on the (only) M.2 NVMe drive in the computer.
   4.5. The system was running fine, I reached the desktop, and then I shut it down.
5. I packed up the computer (since it wasn't for me).
6. When I turned the computer on today, I got the message "Inaccessible Boot Device" on the screen.
7. When I connect the USB with the installer, the computer doesn't detect any drives.
8. In the BIOS, the system recognizes the drive.
9. When I connect the SATA SSD drive from a laptop, the installer also doesn't detect that drive, even though it appears in the BIOS.

I don't know what to do anymore; I've searched through forums, Microsoft's official help, and still nothing. Perhaps someone among you has had a similar issue and might be able to help.

Specifications:
Intel Core i5-13600k
MOBO: Asus TUF B760M-Plus WiFi D4
Drive: WD 1TB M.2 PCIe Gen4 NVMe Blue SN580

I'm not very experienced in building computers; I've done it a few times in my life. However, it seems like the problem lies in the software rather than the hardware.

Today's update:

After disconnecting the M.2 NVMe drive, the installer still doesn't detect the SSD.

After disconnecting and reconnecting the M.2 NVMe in the same port, a BSOD still occurs.

After changing the M.2 NVMe port, the computer behaves the same as in the previous port.

In each of the above scenarios, the USB Installation Tool doesn't detect any of the drives. From the BIOS (even when the SSD is the only installed drive), I cannot select the SSD as the boot drive, but the BIOS sees the disk in storage info.

Comment: Possible the SSD had an early failure.  Try formatting it from a Windows Boot USB.

Comment: I would do it, but neither the first nor the second disk is detected by the Windows Boot Tool.

Comment: Starting to looking like Motherboard or CPU at this point,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found a problem.

After reseting BIOS to default options and disabling Intel Rapid Storage in BIOS, PC just booted up like nothing happened.
If anything will change in the future, I'll post it here.